# Asking federated SPARQL queries with SPARQLWrapper

Tags: python, sparql, sparqlwrapper, federated-queries

How can we ask *federated* queries using [SPARQLWrapper](http://sparql-wrapper.sourceforge.net/)? If it is not possible, is there any alternate library available for making such queries for Python?

Comment: We'll need more information.  (Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself.)  How have you tried to run federated SPARQL queries so far?  Typically this is done with the `service` keyword.  What didn't work?  Also, questions asking for libraries or tools are off topic, so if SPARQLWrapper doesn't handle this, StackOverflow isn't really the right place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask federated queries the same way as normal queries just by adding the *SERVICE* keyword.

Below you may find an example on the endpoint of sparql.org (according to [http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/1830/federated-sparql-on-sparqlorg](https://web.archive.org/web/20130902233255/http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/1830/federated-sparql-on-sparqlorg))

```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper

sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://sparql.org/sparql")

sparql.setQuery("""
select * 
from <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> # bogus, not used
{
  service <http://dbpedia.org/sparql> {
    [] a ?Concept
  }
}
limit 10
""")
results = sparql.query()
results.print_results()
```

Of course, the chosen endpoint have to able to handle the federated query.

Comment: basically the sparql wrapper is agnostic with respects to the query evaluation, which is evaluated by the provided endpoint